# Position input text form and submit button over an image

Tags: html, css

Am trying to add and position an input text form and submit button on top of an image (not over a background image, the commentpaper.jpg) and having a lot of difficulty. This is what I have so far in my html page.

Am new to Html and Css so the simplest way possible would be sweet! Thanks for your help in advance.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Have Your Say</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Have Your Say.">
    <meta name="keywords" content="Have Your Say, Comments">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <img src="commentpaper.jpg" alt="header" width="1050" height="600">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="header">
    </div>
    <div id="nava">
        <ul id="navlist">
            <li><a href="Index.html">Home</a></li> 
            <li><a href="Quiz.html">Weird Stuff</a></li>
            <li><a href="Comments.html">Have Your Say</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <center>
        <form action="" method="GET">
            <textarea name="comments" rows="10" wrap="hard"></textarea>
            <input name="redirect" type="hidden" value="index.html">
            <input name="next_url" type="hidden" value="index.html">
            <br>
            <input type="submit" value="Send">
            <input type="reset" value="Clear">
        </form>
    </center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think you miss `head , body` tag

Comment: For quick response create fiddle

Comment: You need to show us your CSS. Also, what is an `img` doing in your document's `head`?

Comment: make a fiddle for quick answer .

Comment: You shouldn't have an `img` tab within the `head` tag.

Comment: Thanks! Just moved it down into the body tag

Comment: Please explain us what you want to see and what really needs to happen, Create a http://jsfiddle.net/ and add your CSS !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add one div :

```
<div id="absolute">
    <center><form>
    <textarea name="comments" rows="10" wrap="hard">
            </textarea>
            <input name="redirect" type="hidden" value="index.html">
            <input name="next_url" type="hidden" value="index.html">
            <br>
            <input type="submit" value="Send">
            <input type="reset" value="Clear">
            </form>
  </center>
  </div>
```

CSS : i put an absolute position on the div (form)

```
#absolute {
 position: absolute;
top: 50px;
left: 50%;
margin-left:-250px;
width: 500px; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by wrapping the image in a DIV that has `position: relative;` and absolute positioning the form within the wrapper:

You can change the position of the form by adding pixel values to `top`, `bottom`, `right` and `left` CSS properties e.g. `top: 50px;`

Please refer to the **[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w2nP6/)**.

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="header">
</div>
<div id="nava">
    <ul id="navlist">
        <li><a href="Index.html">Home</a></li> 
        <li><a href="Quiz.html">Weird Stuff</a></li>
        <li><a href="Comments.html">Have Your Say</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="form-holder">
    <img src="commentpaper.jpg" alt="header" width="1050" height="600">
    <form action="" method="GET">
        <textarea name="comments" rows="10" wrap="hard"></textarea>
        <input name="redirect" type="hidden" value="index.html">
        <input name="next_url" type="hidden" value="index.html">
        <br>
        <input type="submit" value="Send">
        <input type="reset" value="Clear">
    </form>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
form {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}
.form-holder {
    position: relative; 
}
```

Also note that the `<center>` element is deprecated in HTML 4.01. You should use a DIV with a class or the `<section>` / `<article>` tags where appropriate.

Comment: thanks for your help and will take note about the <center> tags!